# AJP hang 60sec (Tomcat7+apache2.2+mod_jk + CentOS)

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, mod-jk, ajp

I'm using Tomcat+Apache2.2+mod_jk. Really a few requests are hanging 60 ses. 
If anyone has same experiences or knows reasons, please let me know
The stack is:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.sendbb(Native Method)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.output(AjpAprProcessor.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1224)
org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:499)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:402)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteChars(OutputBuffer.java:485)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.flushBuffer(CharChunk.java:464)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.append(CharChunk.java:302)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:527)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:152)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:336)
java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.TokenizedHTMLPage.writeBody(TokenizedHTMLPage.java:35)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.HTMLPage2Content.writeBody(HTMLPage2Content.java:31)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.Content2HTMLPage.writeBody(Content2HTMLPage.java:44)
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.taglib.decorator.BodyTag.doEndTag(BodyTag.java:26)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.config.decorators.main_jsp._jspx_meth_decorator_005fbody_005f0(main_jsp.java:362)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, AJP will not try a new conneciton after a failure for 60 seconds.  You can change this setting with the retry argument in ProxyPass such as this (5 seconds example below)

```
 ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/mfolder/ retry=5
```